# How to randomly fill fixed amount of columns in 2d array with a value in java?

Tags: java, arrays, random, multidimensional-array

Wordy question, let me give an example

The program that I am creating makes a 2D world using a 2D array whose sized is based on user input. In this example the world is a 4 X 10 world

```
----------
----------
----------
----------
```

How would I put 3 Xs in random positions along the bottom Row?

i.e.

```
----------
----------
----------
--x-x---x-
```

but making sure that it is random so that they don't appear in the same row if I run the method again?

Comment: if you say random position it is only in a specific row or for multiple row?

Comment: Just in the bottom row. I will eventually move that row up to the blank row above it and randomly generate more Xs in the now blank bottom row

Comment: Is it okay to use a List?

Comment: Yes a list would be okay

Answer (score 2):

You can try this where you specify the x's in the index `0 , 1 , 2` and the shuffle it using the `shuffle` method of the Collections framework.

```
String [][] data = {{"-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"},{"-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"}};

   data[data.length - 1][0] = "x";
   data[data.length - 1][1] = "x";
   data[data.length - 1][2] = "x";

   Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(data[data.length - 1]));
   for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
       for(String s : data[i]){
           System.out.print(s);
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
```

results:

```
--------
--x-xx--
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rgen = new Random();
    int column = scanner.nextInt();
    int row = scanner.nextInt();

    List<List<Character>> grid = new LinkedList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
        List<Character> aColumn = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            if (rgen.nextBoolean()) {
                aColumn.add('.');
            } else {
                aColumn.add('x');
            }

        }
        grid.add(aColumn);
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't meet the requirement that there be exactly 3 x's in the row.

Comment: This makes sense though. Thank you for the contribution!